# Create a counter to add multiple forms in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

Help me to create a counter to add multiple forms in Yii. So that when you click on the button "Add Address" there is another form of. Sorry for my English!

UserController.php

```
public function actionLoadChildByAjax()
{
    $model = new Address();
    $this->renderPartial('address/_form', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

user/_form.php

```
<div id="address">

</div>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Add Address', '#', array('id' => 'LoadChildByAjax')); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#LoadChildByAjax').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/user/LoadChildByAjax',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#address').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

user/address/_form.php

```
<div class="crow">

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabelEx($model, 'address'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'address', array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::error($model, 'address'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like perhaps you should be using `$('#address').append(data);` in your AJAX success function instead of `html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As addressed in the comment, you'll want to modify your AJAX success function to look like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#address').append(data);
}
```

That way, you're appending the data returned from the AJAX call to your div, instead of replacing it. For more information about those methods, take a look at [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: All good, but the database is recorded only one value. Why so?

Comment: Hm, could it be that the input field you're getting back via the AJAX call has the same `name` value each time?

Comment: bit outside the scope of this question, but offhand you'll want to turn the `name` attribute into an array (think `name="addresses[]"`) and have your form model (or whatever you're using to process the POSTed data loop through, creating (what I assume) a new instance of an Address for each